# Can't play video file using MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

The video file is http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4
I can't play it after copying it into the bundle of an app, then running this:
What's wrong?

```
-(void)showvideo {
    NSNotificationCenter* center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(mPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification) name:MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(readytoplay) name:MPMoviePlayerReadyForDisplayDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    NSBundle* b = NSBundle.mainBundle;
    NSString* res = [b resourcePath];
    NSString* file;
    //  file = @"sr.m4v";
//  file = @"sample_iPod.m4v";
    file = @"big_buck_bunny.mp4";
//  file = @"xxx.mp4";
    NSString* path = [res stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSFileManager* manager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([manager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        NSLog(@"file exists!");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"file does not exist!");
    }

    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSLog(@"url: %@", url);

    self.movieplayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    //  self.movieplayer = [MPMoviePlayerController new];
    self.movieplayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;

    NSLog(@"self.movieplayer: %@, loadState: %d", self.movieplayer, self.movieplayer.loadState);

    [self.movieplayer prepareToPlay];

    NSLog(@"self.movieplayer: %@, loadState: %d", self.movieplayer, self.movieplayer.loadState);
}

-(void)readytoplay {
    NSLog(@"readytoplay");

    [self.movieplayer.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.view addSubview:self.movieplayer.view];

    NSLog(@"self.movieplayer: %@", self.movieplayer);
    self.movieplayer.fullscreen = YES;
    NSLog(@"self.movieplayer: %@", self.movieplayer);
    [self.movieplayer play];
}

-(void)mPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification {
    NSLog(@"mPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification %@, loadState: %d", self.movieplayer, self.movieplayer.loadState);
}
```

Movieplayer property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController* movieplayer;
```

Comment: Did you try with MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you can't modify (append, add, delete) application's bundle on runtime. Secondly, `NSURL` for local files has to be initialised with `fileURLWithPath` method. Try to correct this issues, and if it doesn't play, try to observe `MPMoviePlayerController`'s `loadState` changes, and when its `loadState` is ready to play, then try to play the file. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**
Sorry, my bad, you are not changing app's bundle on the runtime, just go for Second part. And, you can get the url for the file by calling just `[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"file_name" withExtension:@"extension"];`

Answer (score 0):

your URL is wrong. Thats y it didnt work out. Use [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] for url. It should work.